# Problems with displaying iFrame

Tags: php, html, css, iframe

I have a form hosted on a host that supports PHP and I want to display it on desktop and phones in the center of the page, it is perfect on desktop but on phones it does not display at all, what can I change?

HTML + CSS:

```
<iframe src="http://daniell.epizy.com/" scrolling="no" frameBorder="0">Browser not compatible.</iframe>

iframe {
    height:350px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML + CSS from PHP host:

```
<form id="contact" method="POST" action="index.php">
  <div class="test">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Naam" /><br />
    <input  type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" /><br />
    <textarea type="text" name="message" placeholder="Bericht"></textarea><br />
    <div class="message">Bericht verzonden</div>
    <button id="submit" type="submit">
      VERSTUUR
    </button>
  </div>
</form>

html,body {
margin:0!important;
}

.test {
max-width:600px;
text-align:center;
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
-moz-border-radius:6px;
border-radius:6px;
background-color:#fff;
margin:0 auto;
}

input {
margin-bottom:10px;
}

textarea {
height:100px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

input:first-of-type {
margin-top:35px;
}

input,textarea {
font-size:1em;
border:1px solid #cecece;
background:#d7d7d7;
color:#000;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
border-radius:5px;
-moz-background-clip:padding;
-webkit-background-clip:padding-box;
background-clip:padding-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing:border-box;
width:80%;
max-width:600px;
padding:15px 10px 10px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color:#000;
opacity:0.5;
}

button {
margin-top:15px;
margin-bottom:25px;
background-color:#025669;
-ms-border-radius:5px;
-o-border-radius:5px;
border-radius:5px;
border:1px solid #2ABCA7;
-webkit-transition:.5s;
transition:.5s;
display:inline-block;
cursor:pointer;
width:30%;
color:#fff;
padding:12px 45px;
}

button:hover,.button:hover {
background:#026b83;
}

label.error {
font-family:Brandon;
font-size:1em;
display:block;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
background-color:#d89c9c;
width:80%;
color:#ece0c8;
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
-moz-border-radius:6px;
border-radius:6px;
margin:auto;
}

@font-face {
font-family:Brandon;
src:url(Brandon.otf);
}

.message {
font-family:'Source Sans Pro',arial,sans-serif;
font-size:1.1em;
display:none;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
background-color:#2ABCA7;
width:80%;
color:#ece0c8;
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
-moz-border-radius:6px;
border-radius:6px;
margin:auto;
}

:-moz-placeholder,::-moz-placeholder,:-ms-input-placeholder {
color:#000;
}

@media max-width 700px{
body {
padding-top:10px;
}

label.error,input,textarea,button {
width:90%;
}
}
```

My question is: how can I make this iFrame appear with the following media query?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
```

Comment: maybe the issue is not with the ifram, but what is inside the iframe

Comment: Yes, that is what i'm having problems with, I tried so much inside the iFrame but ended up with just margin:0, maybe someone can see what the problem is

Comment: on mobile it's not good but how about desktop when you resize your browser ? as i don't see any particular issue .... it can be related to server and not HTML/CSS, sometimes iframe are blocked

Comment: Why use 2 hosts? why not use one?

Comment: It resizes perfectly on browser, it's just that it is not displayed on mobile phones

Comment: @Niels My main host does not support PHP

Comment: so i guess you have something blocking the iframe

Comment: Why is that your main host if it can't do what you want? for 3 euros a month you can have everything you need.

Comment: I looked it up and safari on iPhone does not block iFrames by default, I have to host it on Github for a school project

Comment: Ik zie trouwens dat je Nederlands bent. Weet je zeker dat je niet alleen de source code hoeft te hosten op Github? Want waarom zou je nou juist daar je site moeten hosten ;)

Comment: Zodat mn mede klasgenoten er ook in kunnen werken

Comment: Oke ik denk dat je een verkeerd idee hebt bij Github. Github is inderdaad om met meerdere mensen te kunnen samen werken maar het testen van je code doe je meestal op je eigen host. Github is meer een man in the middle die zorgt dat iedereen revisies kan maken.

Comment: We testen het ook lokaal maar uiteindelijk pushen we het naar gh, als iemand dan niet kan komen kan hij de bewerkingen nog wel zien. Ik ga nog iets meer proberen om te zorgen dat het iframe zichtbaar is op mobiel

Comment: Veder niet lullig bedoelt maar ik zou niemand aanraden om iframes te gebruiken in welke situatie dan ook. Success verder!